# Kafka producer Bench-marking, unable to make sense out of the result

Tags: apache-kafka

I am doing a simple bench-marking of Kafka producer.
My cluster has 3 Kafka brokers.
I created 2 topics.

topic_one : 1 partition 1 replication

topic_two : 3 partition 1 replication

I written some code eclipse to send messages to the topic.
Send 100,000 messages (1kB each) to both topic (mode: sync)

topic_one takes 33s ~ 34s

**topic_two takes 65s ~ 68s**

Next I open another eclipse and run both application at the same time to simulate 2 producer client sending at the same time.
Send 100,000 messages (1kB each) to both topic (mode: sync)

topic_one takes 39s ~ 43s

**topic_two takes 53s ~ 54s**

I am a little confuse with the **result**.
Understand from this article that having more partition does increase the throughput.

https://engineering.linkedin.com/kafka/benchmarking-apache-kafka-2-million-writes-second-three-cheap-machines

But for topic_two, when I am using 2 client, both the client has a better timing compare to running 1 client alone.

**100MB/65s ~ 68s  VS  200MB/53s ~ 54s**

I understand that this way of bench-marking is not completely accuracy since both application is sending via the same network port. But still I couldn't make sense out of the result.

Is the result expected? Or am I doing it wrong?

Any article/link to help me understand partitions in Kafka will be appreciated too.
Thanks!

Code:

```
  long startTime;
  long endTime;
  int messageNo = 0;
  startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();  
  while (messageNo < 100000) {
        try {
           producer.send(new ProducerRecord<>(topic,
                   messageNo,
                   messageStr)).get();
        } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            // handle the exception
        }
        ++messageNo;
  }
  endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
```

Comment: Are each of the partitions on separate brokers? And if you run both at the same time, wouldn't that mean you are sending twice the amount of data assuming 100,000 is hard-coded? By the way, Kafka has a built-in performance tester... `kafka-producer-perf-test.sh`...

Comment: Yes, the partitions are on separate brokers. I tried doing 200,000 messages using a single application on topic_two, the timing was around 2 times of doing 100,000 messages. Ohh, I didn't know there was a built-in performance tester. Thanks!! I will definitely test it out.

Comment: Could you show your code? It's hard to tell you if you're sending 50k messages in two apps for a total of 100k or running the first 100k app twice with no changes

Comment: Edited the post to include the code, I left out the properties, as it is just setting bootstrap.servers, key.serializer and value.serializer. It is a simple program i reference from [link](https://www.tutorialkart.com/apache-kafka/producer-example-in-apache-kafka). I made some minor changes to send the fixed amount of message. And I am currently only testing sync. What i did was i copy the same project and run on another eclipse, there is slight delay between the start time as I need to click "run" button on both eclipse. Could this simulate 2 app running at the same time? or completely wrong?

Comment: You should realistically be using 2 Threads in one app rather than running it twice. That way you're roughly guaranteed to have both running at the same time. But you're clearly sending **200k total messages** by running that code twice. Not sure why you thought it's still sending only 100k. Also calling `.get()` is a blocking call, which slows down the overall speed

Comment: Yes, it's sending 200k messages, what make me curious was that the timing for sending 200k messages was faster than 100k messages. But then again, like what you comment, it is better to be running it in 2 threads would probably be better. I have tested the performance tester, and it's giving me good benchmarking result. Thank you so much for your help.